# Connot find executable after installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install [KICS](https://kics.io/) into AWS EC2 (Ubuntu). I am suing the one-line install script:

```
curl -sfL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Checkmarx/kics/master/install.sh' | bash
```

However when I run:

```
kics version
```

or

```
which kics
```

It seems like it cannot find the command. It forces me to reboot before being able to see it, however rebooting is not an option in my use-case.

Comment: Use `sudo curl -sfL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Checkmarx/kics/master/install.sh' | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin` for installation and then run `which kics`. By default the command you ran installs in `/home/<user>/bin` directory I think which may not be in your `PATH`. https://docs.kics.io/latest/getting-started/#one-liner_install_script

Comment: @kiner_shah cloud you post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of KICS (https://docs.kics.io/latest/getting-started/#one-liner_install_script):

Run the following command to download and install kics. It will detect your current OS and download the appropriate binary package, defaults installation to ./bin and the queries will be placed alongside the binary in ./bin/assets/queries:

```
curl -sfL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Checkmarx/kics/master/install.sh' | bash
```

If you want to place it somewhere else like /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo curl -sfL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Checkmarx/kics/master/install.sh' | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
```

So by default, it will install in `/home/<user>/bin` folder if using the first command. This folder may not be in `PATH` environment variable because of which `which` command doesn't work.

So, you need to install using the second command in order to install in `/usr/local/bin` which should probably be there in `PATH` and after that `which` command will also work.